# How to find relevant information in HTML code to send login request manually?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to log into a webpage using python's `request` library. It doesn't work and I think the main issue is that I'm forgetting to send some information with the request, but unfortunately I don't know how to figure out *what exactly* is missing.

### Important:

This question is **not** about how to use python to log in into a webpage (there are already enough other questions that answer this [see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285622/login-to-website-using-python-requests), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069524/python-login-on-a-website), etc.]). I'd like to know how to figure out from a given HTML page what I need to send to pass a login screen.

---

### Example

Regardless of that, I think an example can't hurt.

The login I tried to pass is https://mangadex.org/login. Looking at the HTML I found

```
<input autofocus="" tabindex="1" type="text" name="login_username" id="login_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
<input tabindex="2" type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
```

So my first attempt was:

```
import requests 

url = 'https://mangadex.org/login'

payload = {'login_username' : 'XXXXXX',
           'login_password' : 'YYYYYY'}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print p.text
```

Unfortunately I just get redirected to the login screen. So there seems to be something "hidden" that gets send along the log-in information as suggested [here](https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/), see step 1.3. The issue is that I don't really know if the above website has something like this (there were some hidden fields, but they don't seem to be involved in the log in process). If not, I really don't understand how I'm supposed to figure out what is missing.

---

### TL;DR:

Given the html code of a webpage, how do I figure out from the html code what information is necessary to be sent to the website to successfully log in?

Comment: Open the Network tab and look what parameters/sessions/other data is sent along with your login request.

Answer (score 2):

> Given the html code of a webpage, how do I figure out from the html code what information is necessary to be sent to the website to successfully log in?

If you only have `HTML`, maybe you could only know the `Content-Type` and the `name` in the form(Or even the API of login).Mostly, it depends on the code on the backend.Most of pages will use some measure to prevent web-scrape.

if you use the code below in the page you post,:

```
import requests

url = "https://mangadex.org/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login"

payload = {
    "login_password": "xxxxx",
    "login_username": "acs"
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIEBjAQpjLF2kWUAJ',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(response.text)
```

See the result:

```
Hacking attempt... Go away.
```

but if you add `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` in your code:

```
import requests

url = "https://mangadex.org/ajax/actions.ajax.php?function=login"

payload = {
    "login_password": "xxxxx",
    "login_username": "acs"
}
headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIEBjAQpjLF2kWUAJ',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(response.text)
```

This could send the login information normally.

## TL;DR:

I think you couldn't.you need to analyse it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Don't you need to pass the `payload` as `data` to the `s.post()` function?

Comment: @MariusJaeger Oh,I forget to add it, Yes, you need to add it when you really want to login in the page.

Comment: Have you tried loggin in with your method? I get a response that the password or username are wrong (even though they are correct...). I made sure that the URL encoding is correct, i.e. no special characters, but it still fails...

Comment: @MariusJaeger Remove the request header `Content-Type`.