# Python: Requests to upload image to website not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, python-requests

I am trying to use the requests library to upload an image to a file upload.
When I run the code I get a status code 200 meaning it's working but when I reload the page to see if my file was uploaded nothing happens.

Code I used:

```
import requests
url = (r'https://www.roblox.com/build/upload?assetTypeId=13')
files = {'media': open(r'C:\Users\eshbe\Desktop\RojoProject\Python\Orang.jpg','rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.status_code)
```

I uploaded to a site that looks like this. when I printed r.text I got a huge HTML output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTluJ.png

Comment: You need to be probably logged in first. Then you can upload your image.

Comment: im already logged in

Comment: Looking at your code you aren't. Look at `request.session` and, for example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285622/login-to-website-using-python-requests

Comment: So I'm guessing it won't work if I am already logged in to an actual browser?

Comment: No, as it is right now it won't work - browser is another process. You need to be logged in within a session inside the script.